# How to make summernote's colors palette responsive?

Tags: css, colors, responsive-design, editor, summernote

I have a problem with the colors palette appearance in summernote editor.
When the color palette is shown and I decrease the size of the browser window, I see that half of the colors don't show.
**What I want is to find a way to make the colors palette responsive, in order to see all colors.**

Screenshots:

**this is how the problem looks like:**
[image: colors palette not responsive]

Now **the solution I'm thinking (I didn't know how to implement it) is to make the colors palette responsive just like the "image options".**

**this is how it looks like initially:**
[image: image options]

**and this is how it becomes responsive:**

[image: image options responsiveness]

**So, how can we achieve this responsiveness??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all this time, **I had to implement a resize functionality for the palette when the colors caret is clicked:**

```
   $('div[data-name="color"]').on('click', function (e) {
        var rt = ($(window).width() - ($('div[data-name="color"]').offset().left + $('div[data-name="color"]').outerWidth())); //get offset on the right
        var lt = $('div[data-name="color"]').offset().left; //get offset on the left

        var $colorsPalette = $('[data-name="color"] ul.dropdown-menu');

        //if language is arabic and the offset on the left is not big enough to display the horizontal palette>> then display a vertical palette
        if ((__IsArabic == '1' && lt < 340) || (__IsArabic != '1' && rt < 340)) //smaller size needed
        {
            //here I add en empty row to keep distance between the background colors (at the top) and the font colors (bottom)
            if (($colorsPalette.find('li').children().length == 2) && !$(this).parent().hasClass('open')) { //just opened

                //make changes to style to display it correctly
                $colorsPalette.find('.btn-group').first().after('<div class="btn-group" style="margin-top: 30px;"></div>');
                $colorsPalette.css({ 'min-width': '120px', 'height': '470px' });
                $colorsPalette.find('li').css({ 'width': '120px' });
                $colorsPalette.find('li').children().each(function () { $(this).css({ 'margin-right': '5px', 'margin-left': '5px' }) });
                $colorsPalette.find('li').children(":nth-child(2)").width(120);
            }

        } else {

            if ($colorsPalette.find('li').children().length == 3) {
                // undo the changes made (palette back to normal)
                $colorsPalette.find('li').children(":nth-child(2)").remove();
                $colorsPalette.find('li').children().each(function () { $(this).css({ 'margin-right': '', 'margin-left': '' }) });
                $colorsPalette.find('li').css({ 'width': '338px' });
                $colorsPalette.css({ 'min-width': '340px', 'height': '' });
            }

        }

    });
```

I hope this helps someone facing the same problem